# PHP : The target machine is refusing to connect while trying to connect using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have tried almost all the methods, but it shows the error as: "the target machine actively refused it". I have checked the following conditions:
1. The firewall is off.
2. I have checked the xampp listening port number.
Please help.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("10.9.87.199", "root", "tss1923","kiosk");
    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
}else{  
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you try changing the IP address to localhost?

Comment: I'm connecting it to server, so didnt check with localhost.